# Will python .exe files work for others in my company?

Tags: python

I want to make a python script that I can turn into an .exe file and give to others in my company. How can I do this without requiring them to download the Anaconda Distribution, conda installing the correct libraries, etc? Does turning a file into an .exe file take care of this?

Comment: Take a look at pyinstaller. This can bundle all of your app code together along with the python interpreter and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it depends on *how* you turn it into an exe. Exe's can depend on DLLs that the others in your company don't have. However, if you are using a standard tool like https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html pyinstaller, there will be no outside dependencies and you can bundle your python scripts as exes and have no issues with your coworkers.

Answer (score 0):

The existing tools I'm aware of (`PyInstaller`, `py2exe`, `py2app` and `cx_Freeze`) are all designed to encapsulate all dependencies into a single executable, with no external dependencies, so you should be able to distribute the (possibly quite large) executable without worrying about dependencies.

To be clear, there is nothing *intrinsic* to the `.exe` conversion that causes it to avoid dependencies. `.exe` files *can* depend on `.dll` library files, external data files, etc. It's just that most people who want to make such an executable are trying to remove dependencies on the installed Python entirely, not just third-party library dependencies, so the tooling tends to support this use case by avoiding any dependencies at all.